# Learning road map for classical guitar

Tags: guitar, practice, learning, classical-guitar, self-learning

I have no condition to study classical guitar with a teacher (which I think is the best way to learn) because I'm moving much, and I found online lessons are not suitable for me.

I have read some guitar method books, and it seems that they are quite advanced for me, and I found nowhere to begin.

My question is, is there any learning road map for classical guitar (like in mathematics we have to learn simple arithmetic to understand algebra, etc.). I assume my knowledge in this field is zero.

Comment: Not a clue as to where you are in the world - maybe here there and everywhere! But a start point would be to buy grades 1 and 2 of an examining board's books for classical guitar. Depending where you are, there's a few to choose from. Read and play. This idea means your progress is graded - you don't have to take the exams - but it takes you methodically through from the beginning.

Answer (score 7):

This is a somewhat broad question, and one which is highly based in opinions.

As a classical guitarist myself, I recommend the [Suzuki method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suzuki_method#Guitar), but it is somewhat dependent on having a teacher, and can seem very slow as far as repertoire when starting out. It does however start from zero assumed knowledge and in the longterm sets a great base from which to build up. This is however due to the fact that it is technically meant for children, but there is no real reason that it would not work for an adult.

The Suzuki guitar method has nine books, and goes from very beginner pieces where the focus is on tone, to [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwir_9eI9MXXAhWHbiYKHaaKCcsQyCkIJzAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DinBKFMB-yPg&usg=AOvVaw1HE6_a9Az6Wy5hVu56SD_W).

It is also important, no matter which "curriculum" you chose, that you enjoy the pieces you are playing. After you have played some simple tunes to get a feel for the instrument and have worked on your tone, you should think more broadly about which specific kinds of music do you want to play.

> Eg.   Do you want to play more romantic music or more stiff, "Bach-y" music?

Make this decision, then find composers that match it. Or ask here!

If you want something more specific as far as technique, [Scott Tennant](https://music.usc.edu/scott-tennant/) wrote a series of books called [Pumping Nylon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1470635178), which is essentially a textbook of guitar technique. There are also a lot of important things for classical guitarists beyond technique and repertoire. Things such as nail shape and length are also critical parts of getting the best possible result from your playing.

If you are not going to be able to have a teacher, the overall most important thing is to make sure that you are a harsh critic of your playing; do not let mistakes in things such as tone slide, especially as you start out.

There are also tons of fantastic online resources, the only thing is to make sure they are credible.

My "official" recommendation is that you try the Suzuki method, but feel free to try any pieces that catch your fancy. The one thing to remember is to not get yourself in too deep to a piece that you are not quite ready for yet.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of kids in the UK are taught with the Guitarist's Way books by Peter Nuttall and John Whitworth.  They are slightly more kid-orientated, but as such start at the very beginning and work upwards using simple tunes and exercises.  You may find them somewhat too basic (all four are pre-Grade 1), but for the price (often under £5), they may be worth looking out for.

A note about exam books, there is (in the UK at least) an Initial Grade exam which was introduced as young children's fingers are often not developed enough for pieces that are equivalent to Grade 1 on other instruments - if you are going the grade route, this book is where to start.  Lots of adults skip the exam, but there is no reason not to learn to play the pieces.

Enjoy!  You won't be playing Segovia overnight, but who cares if you're enjoying yourself.